# Serial.println() - ATtiny85

Tags: arduino, serial, attiny, attiny85

I have a standalone device with ATtiny85 MCU running Arduino firmware. In the firmware there are serial.println() functions that write its status to the serial port. Since it is a standalone device serial port is not connected to a system or to any other device.
Will this affect the device in any way in the long run?

TIA

Regards,
sri

Comment: Depending on which ATtiny core you use, Serial may be implemented as “software serial” or not at all, AFAIK. The ATtiny85 has no UART so there’s no real hardware serial available. It would probably be better to remove (or comment out) the Serial.println() statements.

Comment: Better to remove all mentions of Serial if you're not using it, it will save space in flash.

Answer (score 2):

No it has no effect other than spending time printing those status strings.